# enumerateGroupsWithTypes loop isn't stopping

Tags: ios, swift, loops, alassetslibrary

I'm using the following code to iterate through eh albums and if it finds the one I need, it should stop further looping.

```
public func importPhotosFromGallery(albumName: String = "Last Imported") {
    fetchAlbum(albumName) { album, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error occurred fetching album: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            if let album = album {
                print("found it! \(album.name)")
            }
        }
    }
}

private func fetchAlbum(albumName: String, completion: (album: ALAssetsGroup?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    assetsLibrary.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(ALAssetsGroupAlbum, usingBlock: { group, stop in
        if group != nil {
            group.setAssetsFilter(ALAssetsFilter.allPhotos())
            print("group name: \(group.name)")
            if group.name == albumName {
                stop.initialize(true)
                completion(album: group, error: nil)
            }
        } else {
            let notFoundError = NSError.createError("Album Not Found")
            completion(album: nil, error: notFoundError)
        }
    }) { error in
        completion(album: nil, error: error)
    }
}
```

I'm changing the `stop` variable's value to `true` after finding the match but it still executes the else block that returns the `notFoundError` at the end. This is the output of the `print` statements.

> group name: Last Imported
>
> found it! Last Imported
>
> Error occurred fetching album: Album Not Found

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs for `enumerationBlock`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:) state

> The block to invoke using each asset group in turn.
>
> When the enumeration is done, enumerationBlock is invoked with group set to nil.

That would mean after setting `stop` to true the `enumerationBlock` is invoked once more, this time with `group` being nil and therefore causing the `completion(album: nil, error: notFoundError)`-branch to be entered.

That results in your completion block getting called twice, once with the correctly found album and once again at the end of the enumeration.

Try inserting a few `print`-statements to see when which branch is entered and what the input is. In particular wether or not the `stop` is already set to `true`.

Comment: Oh crap. I didn't know that. I stuffed the completion handler in the else block inside a if check `if stop.memory.boolValue != true { }`. All good now. Thank you.